# Third argument in strstr is only valid in PHP 5.3.0

Tags: php

Hello I want to get user from an email address,

eg: ***sajid@webspot.com*** then output must be ***sajid***

for this i use below mentioned code

```
$user = strstr($email, '@', true);
```

but an warning occur

**Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr() in /var/www/DataTable/dialog.php on line 3**

& in php manul it is clearly define that the 3rd argument true is only valid for ***PHP 5.3.0***

So is there any string function which could solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$name=strtok($email,"@");
```

Comment: alt `$name = array_shift(explode('@', $email));`

Answer (score 1):

Look in the [User Generated Comments](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php#92923) on the manual page, there are a few implementations.